# List of strings. New variables with those name (without classes). Python

Tags: python, string, list, variables

if one had a list of strings, how could they create variables (empty list objects) with those names?

```
pre_vars= ['list_1','list_2','list_3']

print list_1,list_2,list_3
```

`>>> [],[],[]`

I saw some examples that were similar but they were using classes.  Can this be done without using classes?

Comment: If this was possible, what would you expect their initialized values to be?

Comment: Just empty list objects to fill in later

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Use file directory as input, create a list for every file in the directory, add specific entries from each file into respective lists, use sets to find out the which elements overlap @LegoStormtroopr

Comment: Better use a dict then, you won't be able to create variables with file names that are not valid Python identifiers. Plus this will mess up the namespace.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary, or a list of lists? What happens if you have a directory called 'print'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals):

```
for name in pre_vars:
    globals()[name]= []
```